# MM/DD (Month, Day) in MS Access Table?

Tags: ms-access

Is there anyway to do MM/DD (Month, Day) in MS Access Table?  I do not want the year in the field.

Comment: If you need to store it without year for whatever reason, just use two integer fields. If it is just for display the either use the controls format to specify mm/dd, or use `=Month(myDateField)` when you want to show month, and `=Day(myDateField)` when you want to show day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. But in your query or textbox state the format: mm/dd

Answer (score 1):

Yes! Essentially you would be writing your own data type, except you'd need to repeat all the implementation each time you use this type (because Access isn't the best SQL for this kind of thing e.g. doesn't support Standard SQL's `CREATE DOMAIN` syntax or have anything equivalent). You'd probably want to use two columns for day and month respectively to avoid tiresome text parsing. You'd need column-level constraints e.g. `CHECK ( month BETWEEN 1 AND 12 )`. You'd also need row-level constraints e.g. `CHECK ( month NOT IN ( 4, 6, 9, 11 ) OR day <= 31 );`These constraints will probably slow everything down but better than having no data integrity (maybe a calendar table with foreign keys might be better...?). And you'd have to decide how to deal with the 29-Feb case. You'd probably want to provide CRUD procedures to make things easy on developers using this pseudo type...

But I suspect the answer to your question is... You know when you do "open table" in the Access UI you are not seeing the 'actual' One True Version of the table, right? Access is just a front end to the data stored in a .mdb/.accdb file. It shows the data in tabular form and gives it a format. But don't be fooled into thinking you are seeing "the table itself" or whatever. If you want to see the data in a different format then look at changing the properties of the view in Access or use software to build your own display and format it as you want.